# What does endochorous dispersers means?

Tags: definitions

In an article (Guerrero and Tye, 2009) it talks about endochorous dispersers.

Guerrero, A. M., and A. Tye. 2009. Darwin's Finches as Seed Predators and Dispersers. The Wilson Journal of Ornithology 121:752–764.

> The highest proportions of feces containing viable seeds were of Small
>   Ground Finch (G. fuliginosa) and the ‘‘insectivorous’’ species
>   Woodpecker Finch (Camarhynchus pallidus) and Warbler Finch (Certhidea
>   olivacea). These two may be more important endochorous dispersers than
>   other species that eat more fruit but are better seed predators.
>   Intact seeds were found in 23% of fecal samples; 50% of the samples
>   with intact seeds had viable seeds.

I've looked on google and found nothing...

Do you know what that means?

It seems it relates to mast-fruiting plant species.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the definition [here](http://www.botany.ut.ee/dispersal/manual.html), which is a cool package in R:

> animal - all vertebrate dispersed seeds, without distinction between
>   attached(epichorous) and ingested (endochorous) dispersal of seeds